# Outlook notifications configuration

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-outlook, notifications, microsoft-outlook-2016

My IT department recently pushed out a new version of Outlook 16 for Microsoft 365, running on Windows 10 1809.

Before the new version was deployed, clicking on new email alerts would reliably open the email and the notifications seemed to be part of the Outlook application. After the update, the alerts seem to be standard Windows notifications (ie I assume Outlook is calling a standard Windows notification API) and clicking on the notification reliably marks the email as read, and only occasionally opens the email!

(just to be clear, the previous notification format weren't notifications from rules; they appeared for a few seconds in the bottom right hand corner and would then disappear)

Is there any way to get the old notifications back, or if not, to at least make clicking on the notification reliably open the email?

Comment: I have also noticed it after upgrading a few weeks ago. Clicking on the notifications does not always open them.

Answer (score 0):

What's the version of your Outlook? (File > Office Account > About Outlook). Please make sure you have upgraded your Outlook to the latest version.

Please check if [this Troubleshooting thread about New mail desktop alert](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/cd8804a8-65fd-4b22-bf7a-5063984c7b23/troubleshooting-new-mail-desktop-alert-not-working?forum=outlook) could be helpful to you.

Comment: Thanks for this. I'm using version 16.0.13001.20338. I'll have a look at the link and get back to you.